# Vertex groups and bone's weight painting aren't matching

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

Does the bones weight painting use other place to store it's vertex, because the group matching group vertex didn't match.
Here is what I did:
select a bone In weight painting > the selection in vertex group move to the matching group > I go to edit mode > click on select of the vertex group > the result is massively different from the weight painting.

[image: demo]

Comment: It's very hard to follow your description of the problem.  I suspect you *might* be misunderstanding what some particular operation does, but I'm not sure, because "move to the matching group" and other statements aren't actual operations in Blender.  You might consider trying to rewrite your question, or if new to Blender weight painting, you might consider asking in a forum site, where the ease of conversation would help to deal with basic misunderstandings.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'm indeed new to blender. But It's as in the picture. The painting weight of Hand.L is ok, but in edit mode when I select Hand.L vertex group you can see it contain some vertex in the hip and legs...

Comment: Are you sure you can see the difference between very, very low weight and no weights from the colors?  Don't trust the colors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I even tried to subtract from some of those those vertexes in weight painting mode, but it still the same, and I tried to assign different vertexes the vertex groups but it won't change.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the colors neither. Have you tried to remove the unwanted verts from the group? In Edit mode, select them with the button (like in screenshot 2), then deselect the verts of the hand but keep the unwanted of the hips and legs. Press the "remove" button to remove them from the group.

Comment: It worked, you really can't trust colors. Thank you.